# how to use jquery .live()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an input element with id newline. I'm using `$('#newline').elastic();` to make it elastic using a jquery plugin. The `input#newline` can also be appended through an ajax call in which case the code `$('#newline').elastic();` doesn't work and I've to use something like .live() to make it addressable in future also.

So can anyone help me how to implement .live() in this case??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `$('#newline').elastic();` after your ajax call.
If you insist to use live(), you need to create a custom event after the ajax call by

```
$(this).trigger("newlineAddedEvent");
```

So you can check the event using live

```
$(":input").live("newlineAddedEvent",function(){$(this).elastic();});
```

Comment: do you mean something like `ajax({/*post call, return json as data, append data.text to a list}); $('#newline').elastic();`??

Comment: If you are using $.ajax() , just add the line of code in the success callback. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: what is `$(this)` referring to here??

Comment: Ok.. thanks. adding in the success callback solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the plugin's documentation if it has a setting to make it use live events instead of regular events.
If not you could probably easily hack it to use live events instead of regular events or send a feature request to the developer.